# linux executable doesn't execute but exits silently

Tags: linux, elf

I've got 2 virtual PC with CentOS with the same executable. On 1st pc it runs and gives command line options. On second it doesn't say anything and exits. How can I diagnose second PC? What goes on there? Thanx!

Comment: Use `strace` on the failing Linux PC

Comment: Check the exit status of the command. If it was killed by a signal the exit status will be 128 + signal number.

Comment: Did you try to use gdb?  it will rapidly show you if the process is exiting with a signal.  Do you have the source code?  If so, you can put a break point on the code that prints the command line options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used strace and found out that process was missing libraries that are used to execute 32bit apps on 64bit linux.